# BeanCreationException: Could not inject field:cannot have an existing value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, junit5

I created a testclass for a Job in Spring Batch, which works fine. However I have to add an extension, which extends SpringExtends, and then I get an error saying `nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The field de.orgen.batchprocessing2.DownloadService de.orgen.batchprocessing2.chunkJobsTest.downloadService cannot have an existing value`

My test is:

```
    @SpringBootTest
@SpringJUnitConfig
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
public class chunkJobsTest {
    @Autowired
    private Job secondJob;
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @MockBean
    DownloadService downloadService;


    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @BeforeEach
    public void initializeJobLauncherTestUtils() {
        //   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(secondJob);


    }
    @Test
    void testing(){
                    Map<String, JobParameter> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("test", new JobParameter("test1"));
        when(this.downloadService.downloadFile()).thenReturn("mocked file");
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("step1Chunk"
                   , new JobParameters(param));
    }
}
```

My ConfigurationClass:

```
   @Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ChunkJobs {
    @Autowired
    JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FirstItemReader reader;
    @Autowired
    private FirstItemProcessor processor;
    @Autowired
    private FIrstItemWriter writer;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    


  @Bean
    public Job secondJob(Step step1Chunk){

        return  jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob2")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1Chunk)
                // .next(step2)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("step1Chunk")
    public Step step1Chunk(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1Chunk")
                .<Integer, Long>chunk(3)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
           

 .build();
}
```

The Reader i test in the step:

```
@Component
public class FirstItemReader implements ItemReader<Integer> {
    @Autowired
            DownloadService downloadService;
    List<Integer>  list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    int index =0;
    @Override
    public Integer read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        System.out.println("in itemReader");
        System.out.println(this.downloadService.downloadFile());
        Integer item ;
        if(index<list.size()){
            item = list.get(index);
            index++;
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The extension Class:

```
public class MyExtension extends SpringExtension  {
}
```

It's empty, but replacing it with an implementation which overrides the callback methods doesn't change anything, i get the same error.

The problem seems to be the combination with @MockBean. I want to add functionality to this MyExtension class, but i get the error.

The Full stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not inject field: de.orgen.batchprocessing2.DownloadService de.orgen.batchprocessing2.chunkJobsTest.downloadService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The field de.orgen.batchprocessing2.DownloadService de.orgen.batchprocessing2.chunkJobsTest.downloadService cannot have an existing value

    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.inject(MockitoPostProcessor.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.inject(MockitoPostProcessor.java:380)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.lambda$injectFields$0(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:313)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The field de.orgen.batchprocessing2.DownloadService de.orgen.batchprocessing2.chunkJobsTest.downloadService cannot have an existing value
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor.inject(MockitoPostProcessor.java:386)
    ... 71 more
```

I am using Spring Batch 4.1.2 and spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE, which i cannot change.

Comment: What is the goal that you want to achieve with `MyExtension`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

If you want to extend the testing facilities that involve Spring, you should not extend `SpringExtension` but rather implement a `TestExecutionListener`. This will more likely lead to what you want.

### Long answer

The `SpringExtension` is currently added three times:

- once in the form your `MyExtension` that you're explicitly registering,
- once as `SpringExtension` as implicitly registered by `@SpringJUnitConfig`,
- and once more as `SpringExtension` by `@SpringBootTest`.

The latter two are effectively only one registration as it's the same class, but `MyExtension` is considered to be different. The error you're seeing comes during the second execution after the variable `downloadService` has already been set in the first execution.

The annotation `@SpringJUnitConfig` has no functionality of its own but is meta-annotated with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration`. So to disable `SpringExtension`, you can use `@ContextConfiguration` directly. But with `@SpringBootTest` you should actually be able to remove it completely.

Replacing `@SpringBootTest` is more difficult.

You can try to override the method `SpringExtension::postProcessTestInstance` in `MyExtension` to do nothing, or in particular to not call `TestContextManager::prepareTestInstance`. This may work in your particular case but may just lead to next problem down the road.

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct. However, also @SpringBootTest contains a springExtension, i think the problem is there. If I follow your instructions , the problem is still thre.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! I missed that. This makes solving the problem more difficult. I'll adapt the answer.

Comment: Indeed, a testExecutionListener with exactly the same implementation as a SprngExtension works fine, thanks